# Scrapy Spider cannot Extract contents of web page using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I have scrapy spider and i am using xpath selectors to extract the contents of the page,kindly check where i am going wrong

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from medicalproject.items import MedicalprojectItem
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector 
from scrapy import Request  


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
      name = "medical"
      allowed_domains = ["yananow.org"]
      start_urls = ["http://yananow.org/query_stories.php"]

rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'display_story.php\?\id\=\d+']),callback='parse_page',follow=True),       
    )

def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td')
    items = []
    for title in titles:
        item = MedicalprojectItem()
        item["patient_name"] = title.xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/img[1]/text()").extract()
        item["stories"] = title.xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/font/p/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return(items)
```

Comment: You're XPaths are way off. You are not going to get the patient name out of the `display_story.php` you need to extract it from the table on the `query_stories.php` index.

Remember you can test XPaths in the Chrome console using `$x(xpath-here)`

Comment: i am interested with the particular story of a patient which is displayed in display_Story.php, i am suppose to extract the entire story of a single patient one by one

Comment: @Ash as as example, display_story.php?id=1023, from this page, i need a name and the full story

Comment: I've ran your XPaths against that page and `/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/img[1]/text()` returns an empty array because it doesn't exist. Best thing I can think of is using `'/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/font/p[last()]/text()'` and then removing the extra characters after the name using `name.split("'", 1)[0]` but that will only work for some pages. You really need to scrape the name from the table on the index page.

Comment: I used chrome to copy this xpath and i cant figure out why i cant get the data, OK i can get the name from the index, but i need to get the entire story also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code so here is a different approach.

I opted against a `CrawlSpider` to have more control over the scraping process. Especially with grabbing the `name` from the query page and the story from a detail page.

I tried to simplify the `XPath` statements by not diving into the (nested) table structures but looking for patterns of content. So if you want to extract a story ... there must be a link to a story.

Here comes the tested code (with comments):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    story = scrapy.Field()

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'medical'
    allowed_domains = ['yananow.org']
    start_urls = ['http://yananow.org/query_stories.php']

    def parse(self, response):

        rows = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"display_story")]')

        #loop over all links to stories
        for row in rows:
            myItem = MyItem() # Create a new item
            myItem['name'] = row.xpath('./text()').extract() # assign name from link
            story_url = response.urljoin(row.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]) # extract url from link
            request = scrapy.Request(url = story_url, callback = self.parse_detail) # create request for detail page with story
            request.meta['myItem'] = myItem # pass the item with the request
            yield request

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        myItem = response.meta['myItem'] # extract the item (with the name) from the response
        text_raw = response.xpath('//font[@size=3]//text()').extract() # extract the story (text)
        myItem['story'] = ' '.join(map(unicode.strip, text_raw)) # clean up the text and assign to item
        yield myItem # return the item
```

Comment: Thank you so much, perfect solution!